# Declaring variable (difference between int c; and int c=new int();

Tags: c#

What is the difference between:

int c;
int c=new int();

Sometimes I use the first one and it works perfectly, but sometimes when I use inside a loop it doesn´t work.

this work:

```
    public int[] junta(Table ent,int j)
    {
         int[] matriz=new int[count(ent)];
         int k;
         k = 0;
         for (int i = fline(ent); i <= count(ent) + 1; i++)
         {
             if (Convert.ToString(ent.Cells[j, 3].Value) == Convert.ToString(ent.Cells[i, 3].Value))
             {

                 matriz[k]=Convert.ToInt32(ent.Cells[i,0].Value);
                 k++;

             }

         }
   }
```

this doesn´t work:

```
public int[] junta(Table ent,int j)
{
     int[] matriz;
     int k;
     k = 0;
     for (int i = fline(ent); i <= count(ent) + 1; i++)
     {
          if (Convert.ToString(ent.Cells[j, 3].Value) == Convert.ToString(ent.Cells[i, 3].Value))
          {

               matriz[k]=Convert.ToInt32(ent.Cells[i,0].Value);
               k++;

           }

      }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of both?

Comment: Please provide an example of when it doesn't work.

Comment: ... also an example of *how* it doesn't work. In C# you can't *not* create an integer when you declare one.

Comment: @Arran - They won't both be 0 since `int c;` does not assign a value to `c`.

Comment: I guess he sometimes declares it in the class scope and, in that case, it works as if int c = 0

Comment: Nitpicking, but declaring it "in the class scope" declares a field, not a variable.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you're right; my bad!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: A field is a variable, just not a *local* variable. Local variables, formal parameters, fields, array elements and dereferenced pointers are all variables. Remember, a variable is a *mutable storage location*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that this:

```
int c;
```

does not assign a value to the variable, so if you try to access the variable afterwards the compiler will complain with this:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'c'

However if you do this:

```
int c = new int();
```

then you might as well write this:

```
int c = 0;
```

and this will assign a value to it.

You can test the following two code snippets and observe their difference:

```
int c;
int a = c;
```

with this:

```
int c = 0; // try = new int(); as well if you want to
int a = c;
```

Answer (score 6):

if you declare `int c` as a field (class variable) the framework will assign it to zero

if you declare the `int c` inside a method you cannot use it before being assigned, hence this does not work

```
public void TEST()
  {
     int c;
     int a= c*2;
  }
```

To make it work you must assign it before using it. It doesn't have to be in the same line as the one being declared. This is perfectly fine:

```
public void TEST(bool b)
  {
     int c;
     if(b)
       c = 2;
     else
       c = 4;
     int a= c*2;
  }
```

When using it as a field it is auto-assigned, so this is okay

```
class TestClass
{
  int c;
  public void TEST()
  {
     int x = c*2; // c has the value of zero.
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The framework auto-assigns class variables using `default(typeof(variableType))` where `variableType` is the type of the variable being assigned

Comment: Actually is `default(variableType)` and not `default(typeof(variableType))`

Answer (score 3):

`int c` declares a variable of type `int`. `int c = new int()` declares a variable of type `int` and assigns it a value (0).

You cannot read a local variable before assigning it a value, so the following will not compile:

```
int c;
int a = c;
```

while the following will:

```
int c = new int();
int a = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use it in loop it will give you the las t element in whole array so for that You have that declare it outside the loop